# mysql php query : why does a including not equal affect the results

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In a mysql query with 5000 records, 
in the table: subscriptions [id autoincrement int, name varchar64, archive tinyint4 ]

i'm passing the following sql

```
$sqlg = "SELECT * FROM subscriptions where archive != 1  order by id desc limit 0,24";
```

the above returns 
records between 3061 - 3012

If i remove the where clause,

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions order by id desc
```

it returns, records between 5066 - 5037 which is the correct result i'm looking for with archive having the value of NULL or 0.
Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Read the [documentation on how NULL behaves in comparisons](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/working-with-null.html).

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is not the same as `0`. It simply is unknown, so if you want to check for `NULL` also, use `IS NULL`

```
SELECT * 
FROM subscriptions 
where archive = 0 OR archive IS NULL 
order by id desc 
limit 0, 24
```